# DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to set the client_info value to differentiate between different clients.

These are the scripts that I am running to test.

Step 1:SYS SCHEMA

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE;
```

Step 2:HR SCHEMA

```
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_NAME );
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE( 'CHECK','select' );

select                                      
    a.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULL_NAME
from                                        
    HR.EMPLOYEES a                                      
where                                       
    a.DEPARTMENT_ID = '40'
;
```

Step 3:SYS SCHEMA

```
select
    *
from
    (
        select
           a.SQL_ID
          ,a.SQL_FULLTEXT
          ,to_char( a.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )                                                                                as LAST_ACTIVE_TIME
          ,a.SERVICE
          ,b.SCHEMANAME
          ,b.CLIENT_INFO
          ,a.MODULE
          ,a.ACTION
        from
            GV$SQL a
        left outer join GV$SESSION b
        on
            (
                b.SQL_ID = a.SQL_ID
            )
        where
            a.EXECUTIONS != 0
    )
    c
where
    c.MODULE like '%CHECK%'
order by
    c.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME desc ;
```

The MODULE and ACTION columns are getting the values but the CLIENT_INFO is not showing anything.

Is there anything I am missing?

**Update:**
I have also tried with no luck

```
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO( SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','ip_address') );
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO( '10.10.10.10' );
```

Comment: Do you open a new connection for "Step 3"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No. These operations were done in two parallel sessions on SQL Developer

Comment: Do you get anything from this: `SELECT * FROM V$SESSION WHERE CLIENT_INFO IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Just look into `V$SESSION WHERE CLIENT_INFO IS NOT NULL`. And don't get confused between SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit By running your query, I get 10 to 15 unnecessary results out of which one record has the expected CLIENT_INFO value. But I get this for only one query `select * from employees;` But not for the above mentioned query nor for `select * from departments`. I got to know this because i get the SQL_ID column value to cross check with V$SQL view. but no SQL_ID for other queries?

Comment: `SET_CLIENT_INFO` is related to a **Session**, not to a single SQL Statement. What do you try to achieve? Try `SELECT * FROM V$SESSION WHERE USERNAME = {the user you used for connection}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You opened my eyes.. I can't believe I was this dumb not using my head and my knowledge but I was desperately trying to fix some faulty bug.. Anyway thanks. Make your last comment as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET_CLIENT_INFO` is related to a Session, not to a single SQL Statement.

**DO THIS**

Step 1:SYS SCHEMA

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE;
```

Step 2:HR SCHEMA

```
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_NAME );
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE( 'CHECK','select' );
```

Step 3:SYS SCHEMA

```
SELECT
    a.SQL_ID
   ,a.CLIENT_INFO
   ,a.MODULE
   ,a.ACTION
   ,a.SCHEMANAME
   ,a.USERNAME
FROM
   V$SESSION a
WHERE
    a.MODULE = 'CHECK';
```