# V$SESSION.CLIENT_INFO column is not getting any data

Tags: database, oracle

I have used

```
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('My program');
```

but still I am not getting the value in CLIENT_INFO column of V$SESSION table for the queries that i am executing/executed.

However the MODULE and the ACTION columns are getting the set values by using

```
EXEC DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE( 'CHECK','SELECT' );
```

am i missing anything ?

Comment: "*for the queries that i am executing/executed*" You need to show us the code. How exactly are you using it? What do you mean by queries? Are you expecting to do it in SQL?

Comment: @LalitKumarB Please refer my other question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472201/dbms-application-info-set-client-info-not-working).